Vintage (50s-60s?) SF short story where a young alien roots to the ground during rainy season
The setting is an alien planet. The protagonist is a humanoid alien youth named Spet. The other main character is a human observer monitoring Spet's village, who gradually befriends Spet. The human is attempting to learn about the alien culture and is particularly concerned with a rite of passage he has heard about, wherein the candidates for adulthood are hung by their feet from the branches of tall trees during the rainy season, until the rain passes. The observer thinks it is barbaric and urges the elder to abandon it, which suggestion is met with agitation and refusal on the part of the elder.
When the rains come the observer comes and convinces Spet to come with him. The two walk away across sodden ground and through a rivulet, where Spet begins to transform by sending roots from his feet into the ground and developing fern-like fronds on his extremities, ending with him becoming a sessile plant-like adult form.

Almost certainly a dupe of Short story: man rescues alien from cruel hanging ceremony, but alien turns into a shrub - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unhuman_Sacrifice

Hi Tom. Please let us know if the story is Unhuman Sacrifice so we can mark this as a duplicate.

100% certain, seeing as the alien youth in "Unhuman Sacrifice" is named Spet.

You can read the story at the Internet Archive: https://archive.org/details/Astounding_v62n03_1958-11_EXciter-LennyS/page/n99/mode/2up

"Unhuman Sacrifice", a 1958 novelette by Katherine Maclean which which was also the answer to the old question Short story: man rescues alien from cruel hanging ceremony, but alien turns into a shrub among others; first published in Astounding Science Fiction, November 1958, available at the Internet Archive. You may have read it in one of these compilations.
ISFDB synopsis:

An alien planet is visited by a human clergyman who intends to bring them to God, beginning with stopping the practice of a barbaric spring ritual.

The Earthmen learn about the strange alien custom from a native youth named Spet:

"The natives, they actually do it." Henderson clenched the cigar between his teeth and lit it with savage jerky motions. "I asked Spet. No mistake in the translator this time. He said, yes, they hang the young men upside down in trees after the first spring rain. And yes, it hurt, and yes sometimes one died, and no, he didn't know why they had to do this or what it was for. Ha!" Henderson threw the cigar away and began to pace again, snarling.

They decide to try to save Spet from hanging:

"So let him try to stop them, just by talking." Henderson who had stopped to listen, began to pace again, glowering at the floor. "That flapping mouth! Talking won't do it. Talking by itself never does anything. I'm going to do it the easy way. I'm going to kidnap Spet, and keep them from getting him.

The Earthmen (whom Spet thinks are ghosts) cut Spet down from the tree where he was hanging and lead him off to their spaceship:

The two started off through the forest, beckoning Spet to follow. He wondered if he were a ghost already. Perhaps the ghosts had taken him to be a ghost without waiting for him to die. That was nice of them, and a favor, possibly because they were kinfolk. He followed them.

Spet turns into a plant:

All thought stopped. As the water rushed into his lungs, the rooted sea creature that was the forgotten adult stage of Spet's species began its thoughtless pseudo-plant existence, forgetting everything that had ever happened to it. Its shape changed.

